# FFI - Attach function with argument type FILE?

Tags: ruby, ffi, ruby-ffi

How would I wrap a function that accepts an argument of type FILE using FFI in Ruby?

```
int fprintf ( FILE * stream, const char * format, ... );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not type `FILE`, but `FILE *`.  Just another `:pointer` like any other.

If you need to build a struct to examine the contents of the memory pointed to, you need to find the definition of `FILE` in your system's `stdio.h` and reproduce it as an FFI struct.